# Binary search without recursive

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am writing code of records and non-recursive binary searches. I have problems when using the binary search since when I try to do it, the printing of the values ​​does not receive me correctly (the array is already ordered) and I do not know what error I may have there

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void registro();
void consultaprestamo();

struct datos {
  int numprestamo;
  char nombre[10];
  char direccion[10];
  int telefono;
  int importesoli;
}
datos[10];

int x = 0;
char busqueda;

char auxn[10];
int j, k, aux;

int inf, sup, mit, dato, n = 20;
int nucontrol;

int main(void) {
  char opcion;

  do {
    printf("A) people registration\n");
    printf("D) Specific consultation for loans\n");
    printf("F)exit\n");
    printf("Opcion: ");
    scanf("%s", &opcion);

    switch (opcion) {
        case 'A':
          registro();
          break;

        case 'D':
          consultaprestamo();
          break;
    }
  } while (opcion != 'F');

}
```

record data

```c
void registro() {
  char continuar;

  do {
    printf("\n*****************\n");
    printf("Loan number: ");
    scanf("%d", & datos[x].numprestamo);
    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%s", datos[x].nombre);
    printf("adress: ");
    scanf("%s", datos[x].direccion);
    printf("number phone: ");
    scanf("%d", & datos[x].telefono);
    printf("Amount requested: ");
    scanf("%d", & datos[x].importesoli);
    x++;

    printf("Enter another record? y/n: ");
    scanf("%s", &continuar);

  } while (continuar != 'n');

}
```

binary search

```c
void consultaprestamo() {

  for (k = 1; k < x; k++) {
    for (j = 0; j < x - 1; j++) {
      if (datos[j].numprestamo > datos[j + 1].numprestamo) {

        aux = datos[j].numprestamo;
        datos[j].numprestamo = datos[j + 1].numprestamo;
        datos[j + 1].numprestamo = aux;

        aux = datos[j].telefono;
        datos[j].telefono = datos[j + 1].telefono;
        datos[j + 1].telefono = aux;

        aux = datos[j].importesoli;
        datos[j].importesoli = datos[j + 1].importesoli;
        datos[j + 1].importesoli = aux;

        strcpy(auxn, datos[j].nombre);
        strcpy(datos[j].nombre, datos[j + 1].nombre);
        strcpy(datos[j + 1].nombre, auxn);

        strcpy(auxn, datos[j].direccion);
        strcpy(datos[j].direccion, datos[j + 1].direccion);
        strcpy(datos[j + 1].direccion, auxn);

      }
    }
  }
  for (j = 0; j < x; j++) {
    printf("loan number: %d\n", datos[j].numprestamo);
    printf("phone number: %d\n", datos[j].telefono);
    printf("Import requested: %d\n", datos[j].importesoli);
    printf("\nName: %s\n", datos[j].nombre);
    printf("adress: %s\n", datos[j].direccion);
  }

  inf = 0;
  sup = j;

  printf("write the number control");
  scanf("%d", & nucontrol);

  while (inf <= sup) {
    mit = (inf + sup) / 2;
    if (datos[mit].numprestamo == nucontrol) {

      printf("dato %d encontrado posicion %d\n", nucontrol, mit);
      printf("loan number: %d\n", datos[j].numprestamo);
      printf("phone number: %d\n", datos[j].telefono);
      printf("Import requested: %d\n", datos[j].importesoli);
      printf("\nName: %s\n", datos[j].nombre);
      printf("adress: %s\n", datos[j].direccion);

      break;
    }
    if (datos[mit].numprestamo > nucontrol) {
      sup = mit;
      mit = (inf + sup) / 2;
    }
    if (datos[mit].numprestamo < nucontrol) {
      inf = mit;
      mit = (inf + sup) / 2;
    }

  }

}
```

I tried to nest the while with the for of the ordered array but I couldn't, I also tried to make several changes of variables.

Comment: @harold but the label that I put belongs to the C language right? Or are there variants of the C language apart from C++?

Answer (score 1):

Your code will cause an infinite loop when try to find an element that does not eixst. Try this:

```
// Always let inf indexs to first element and sup to last element after each loop
inf = 0;
sup = x - 1;
while (inf <= sup) {
    mit = (inf + sup) / 2;
    if (datos[mit].numprestamo == nucontrol) {
        // printf ...
        break;
    } else if (datos[mit].numprestamo > nucontrol) {
        sup = mit - 1;
    }  else {
        inf = mit + 1;
    }
}
*/
```